# Enumerations in C# negative side effects of using a negative number

Tags: c#

In a C# enumeration, are there any negative side effects of using a negative number?

I am modelling response codes and one of the codes in negative. This compiles but I want to know if there are any negative side effects to this.

```
public enum ResponseCodes
{
    InvalidServerUserPasswordCombo = -1,

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> negative side effects of using a negative number

Clearly, with any underlying signed type, any bitwise operations are going to get "interesting" very quickly.

But using an enum as a collection of related constants can quite happily use negative values.

Comment: An `enum` without `[Flags]` is unlikely to be used with bitwise operations (although, of course, it's  not prohibited).

Comment: @dtb: plus the numbers has to be in a power of 2 :) So this is *definitely* not a case here..

Comment: @Tigran Not true, you can have a value in a enumeration that is a pre-combined name for multiple other flags. Using or to combine allows this to work.

Comment: @Richard: I was talking about *bitwise* operations on `enum`. If you want correctly manage enumeration *betwise* operations the `ins`s assigned to members of that enum **has to be** the power of 2. `{1,2,4,8...}`

Comment: @Tigran: I know what you were referring to. And powers of two is ***not*** a requirement. `[Flags]enum Test { A = 1, B = 2, Both = 3}` works fine. (Give it a try.)

Comment: @Richard: your assumption is not correct.  Check out this enum instead: `enum Test { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, All = 5}`. Assign to enum variable `All` and you will see that `All` could be `B |C` **or** `A|D`. You can not in *unique* way understand content off the enum value. Instead, if the values are in power of 2, this is mathematically precise.

Comment: @Tigran I think we are talking an cross purposes. The language and runtime will work with overlapping flags (eg. an `Combination` value that is a set of other values or'ed together). The underlying (distinct) flags do need to be powers of two. I think you are assuming I am conflating the two things. (I had previously assumed bitwise operations were only allowed on `Flags` enums: when I found I was wrong I discovered `Flags` is only really a hint to the user of the enum, it has no real meaning at runtime.)

Comment: If you're using `[Flags]`, -1 is a handy shortcut to refer to *all flags*. If you do `public enum Things{Thing1 = 1, Thing2 = 1<<1, All = ~0}`, by writing "negate zero" you're essentially specifying that all flags (even ones you haven't specified yet) are set. The value of ~0 is -1. So there's an instance where if you used flags and a negative number you'd run into weirdness. (understanding OP is not using flags though)

Answer (score 13):

There's no negative side effects, however, keep in mind that an enum gets initialized to zero in this instance:

```
class YourClass {
    public ResponseCodes ResponseCode { get; set; }
}
```

Providing just negative one will have an undesired impact for any users of the class (unless they initialize it.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is 7 years late but I haven't seen the point made anywhere else.

There is a minor negative side effect when using negative numbers for enums. If you want to cast a negative number to an enum you'll need to ensure the number is in brackets to avoid a compile error, e.g.:

```
class YourClass {
    ResponseCodes rc = (ResponseCodes)(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the enum is a value with an integer type and this can be any value from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647! :)